# How did my commit get lost during an interactive rebase?

Tags: git

I have four linear commits on one branch that I update using `git rebase --interactive`. They are:

```
small fixes to irrelevant files
FeedbackViewController tests
live feedback tests
poke build bot
```

I managed to lose the commit titled "FeedbackViewController". Now I have only:

```
small fixes to irrelevant files
live feedback tests
poke build bot
```

where did I lose this commit, and how can I get it back at the locating of the third-oldest commit?
Here's the output of `git reflog --date=relative`:

```
b2681e4 HEAD@{21 seconds ago}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/end
b2681e4 HEAD@{24 seconds ago}: checkout: moving from end to b2681e4
b2681e4 HEAD@{31 minutes ago}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/end
b2681e4 HEAD@{31 minutes ago}: rebase: small fixes to irrelevant files
6f80728 HEAD@{31 minutes ago}: rebase: live feedback tests
56b5212 HEAD@{31 minutes ago}: rebase: poke build bot
10bc997 HEAD@{33 minutes ago}: checkout: moving from end to 10bc997faa7d5cad52c5b3f1dc25816c13220187^0
422f15a HEAD@{25 hours ago}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/end
422f15a HEAD@{25 hours ago}: rebase: small fixes to irrelevant files
79d7596 HEAD@{25 hours ago}: pull --rebase: live feedback tests
52072ec HEAD@{25 hours ago}: pull --rebase: poke build bot
62c8870 HEAD@{25 hours ago}: checkout: moving from end to 62c887017d969d98ec5874698c82f94523fe5ac6^0
ca2f134 HEAD@{25 hours ago}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/end
ca2f134 HEAD@{25 hours ago}: rebase: small fixes to irrelevant files
8bce052 HEAD@{25 hours ago}: rebase: FeedbackViewController tests
d581615 HEAD@{25 hours ago}: rebase: live feedback tests
c9adb82 HEAD@{25 hours ago}: rebase: poke build bot
e556052 HEAD@{26 hours ago}: checkout: moving from end to e556052f0db5c674e4145e56001df08cb809f936^0
399758d HEAD@{26 hours ago}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/end
399758d HEAD@{26 hours ago}: rebase: small fixes to irrelevant files
3f6385d HEAD@{26 hours ago}: rebase: FeedbackViewController tests
ba01791 HEAD@{26 hours ago}: rebase: live feedback tests
e9159db HEAD@{26 hours ago}: rebase: poke build bot
```

**ADDED QUESTION**:

I'm especially curious about these lines:

```
422f15a HEAD@{25 hours ago}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/end
422f15a HEAD@{25 hours ago}: rebase: small fixes to irrelevant files
79d7596 HEAD@{25 hours ago}: pull --rebase: live feedback tests
52072ec HEAD@{25 hours ago}: pull --rebase: poke build bot
```

How did I manage to `pull --rebase` and `rebase` in the same line? Usually when I do a `pull --rebase`, it updates all four of them at once, as in:

```
18cb678 HEAD@{2 days ago}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/end
18cb678 HEAD@{2 days ago}: pull --rebase: small fixes to irrelevant files
744ce78 HEAD@{2 days ago}: pull --rebase: FBFeedbackViewController tests
7fd9af4 HEAD@{2 days ago}: pull --rebase: live feedback tests
1b7aa06 HEAD@{2 days ago}: pull --rebase: update feedback when MQTT message is received
```

**SOLUTION**:

By using `git reflog branch-name` rather than `git reflog`, I can see one entry for the entire rebase operation, so I can go back to that state in my project.

The output of `git reflog branch-name --date=relative` looks like this:

```
b2681e4 end@{71 minutes ago}: rebase finished: refs/heads/end onto 10bc997faa7d5cad52c5b3f1dc25816c13220187
422f15a end@{26 hours ago}: rebase finished: refs/heads/end onto 62c887017d969d98ec5874698c82f94523fe5ac6
ca2f134 end@{26 hours ago}: rebase finished: refs/heads/end onto e556052f0db5c674e4145e56001df08cb809f936
399758d end@{26 hours ago}: rebase finished: refs/heads/end onto 9276926e7fe7417db622e42da44e54eac4db1f85
a8ca29d end@{2 days ago}: rebase -i (finish): refs/heads/end onto bfe8d25
18cb678 end@{2 days ago}: rebase finished: refs/heads/end onto 967a525790be38e06b42ff314f47821ec867403f
21c2da4 end@{2 days ago}: rebase finished: refs/heads/end onto f94d81aa5c3ecf6445db06692dee4f6c40d96c0b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you accidentally deleted it from the interactive rebase recipe list, or it ended up being identical to a commit that you're rebasing on top of and therefore was skipped.

Comment: Thanks. This answers how did I lose the commit. The second question I asked is, "how can I get it back at the locating of the third-oldest commit?" One minute, I'll check out a commit it may have been smashed with. Then I could split it.

Comment: @RosePerrone: Use the reflog of the branch, instead of `HEAD`. It will only have 1 entry for the entire rebase operation. This way you can back out the rebase and start over. A simple `git reset --hard @{1}` should do it (because `@{1}` will implicitly use the current branch instead of `HEAD`).

Comment: Thanks! Why is the behavior of `git reflog` different for the current branch and `HEAD`? `man git-reflog` doesn't mention it. What's the best way to save the work I did since the commit I want to reset to, on all the stacked commits?

Comment: Please see the "ADDED QUESTION"

Comment: @RosePerrone: `HEAD` tracks every single change made to `HEAD`. During a rebase, every rebased commit causes a change to `HEAD`, so if you're rebasing 6 commits, you'll see at least 6 entries added to the reflog for the rebase. However, only one commit is added to the branch's reflog.

Comment: why is only one commit added to the branch's reflog? Is it that it would be redundant to track every change, when `HEAD` does that for us?

Comment: @RosePerrone: Because the branch doesn't actually move until the rebase is done. You can verify this yourself. If you're in the middle of a rebase, and you `git reset --hard branchname`, you end up back where you started. The branch never moved, only `HEAD` did during the rebase. It's only when the rebase is done that the branch is updated to the final result.